# django vs jsp for production scale applications

Tags: django, jsp

I have done large scale production grade web application using JSP, understand the difficulties of jvm tuning, web containers and how to scale content (static and dynamic). In the recent years there is not much development in JSP with the exception of JSTL and I am not sure whether this will change in near future; I am considering Django as an alternative to host production grade, high scaling application.

Considering my java/JSP experience what are the pros and cons i should be aware of when it comes to DJango particularly when it comes to scaling and performance

Answer (score 1):

**Django** itself is framework based on python. If you are about to use it in production then it is fine. Similar way **JSP** stands for *JAVA server pages* it is used with java related frameworks. i.e MVC architecture, servlets, etc.

Now moving to your question, Both technologies are highly scalable and used for robust solution. The main difference is language, readability and speed of execution.

Below are some differences between both technologies

- **Django** is based on *python* which is scripting language/ interpreted language so code is interpreted which is quite slower than compiled language. Code is written in *python* which provides high readability. But when it comes to scalability it is highly scalable.
- **JSP/ Servlet** is based on *java* which is compiled language. So the code is compiled which gives bonus of faster execution. JSP/ Servlet architecture is also highly scalable but the coin side is *readability*. But it is also used for building scalable enterprise applications.

To conclude, both technologies are highly scalable and efficient to make robust applications.